# Timestamp interpreted different on local machine and on gitlab pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, jestjs, gitlab-ci

I have the following code to convert a timestamp to text format.

```
export default function convertTime(time) {
    let date = new Date(time);
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let day = date.getDate();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
    return day + "." + month + "." + year + " " + hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
}
```

and my test with jest is the following:

import convertTime from "../../../src/components/Base/TimeConverter";

```
describe("Test time converter", function () {
    it("Time converter should return valid string for a certain hard coded time stamp in milliseconds", function () {
        const result = convertTime(1585575410 * 1000);
        const expected_result = "30.3.2020 15:36";
        expect(result).toBe(expected_result);
    });
});
```

on my computer the test passes:

```
lara@dirk:~/Desktop/git/JS/kiwi$ npm run test

> kiwi@0.1.0 test /home/lara/Desktop/git/JS/kiwi
> env-cmd -f .env.dev jest --passWithNoTests

 PASS  tests/components/Base/TestTimeConverter.spec.js
 PASS  tests/others/TestEnvironmentVariables.spec.js

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.349s
Ran all test suites.
```

however on gitlab it fails:

```
$ npm run test
 > kiwi@0.1.0 test /builds/kiwi4/frontend
 > env-cmd -f .env.dev jest --passWithNoTests
 PASS tests/others/TestEnvironmentVariables.spec.js
 FAIL tests/components/Base/TestTimeConverter.spec.js
   ● Test time converter › Time converter should return valid string for a certain hard coded time stamp in milliseconds
     expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
     Expected: "30.3.2020 15:36"
     Received: "30.3.2020 13:36"
       5 |         const result = convertTime(1585575410 * 1000);
       6 |         const expected_result = "30.3.2020 15:36";
     > 7 |         expect(result).toBe(expected_result);
         |                        ^
       8 |     });
       9 | });
       at Object.<anonymous> (tests/components/Base/TestTimeConverter.spec.js:7:24)
 Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
 Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
```

My question is why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GitLab runner instance and your computer have different timezone.

Quote from dzone.com

> When you call getTime method on Date object you get the number of
>   milliseconds from Unix epoch. Although your current Date object keeps
>   time with some offset getTime gives seconds in UTC. Keep this in mind
>   when creating timestamps if you are not living on zero-meridian.
>
> ```
> var currentDate = selectedDate;          
>
> var currentTime = currentDate.getTime();
> ```
>
> This is pretty awkward, unexpected and unintuitive behavior but you
>   have to keep in mind that all date and time calculations must use same
>   time system to give appropriate results.

You will need to get the attributes in UTC timezone OR calculate the timezone offset with:

```
new Date(timestamp + (offset * 1000))
```

And you can calculate the offset of your client with:

```
const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: Even those on zero–meridian need to take care as their region may observe daylight saving. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I bet you are located someplace in the US Central Daylight time zone, and gitlab in Pacific. Your test is timezone sensitive. (Hint: when times mismatch by exactly some number of hours, it's usually a timezone problem.)

Javascript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) methods like [`.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) are inherently sensitive to the timezone setting. The methods like [`.getUTCFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) aren't.

You can arrange to run nodejs with the `TZ` environment variable set so it doesn't accept the local default. You need to do this in your pipeline for this test to pass.

```
 env TZ='UTC' node yourcommand
```

Or you can try putting this line of js right at the top of your test.

```
 process.env.TZ = 'UTC'
```